# Objects within a parent div are still overflowing

Tags: html, css

Codepen link: [removed for privacy]

(Ignore the search button, I am mainly concerned with results displayed within it's parent element of #results_container).
On the actual app, results will be generated based on a search term,

I have the overflow set to "scroll", but as you can see, the bottom result still overflows.  What gives?

```
#results_container {

  height: 430px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-top: 5px;

}
```

Comment: I might not be understanding the issue, as I don't see the overflow you're referring to. Which part, specifically, is overflowing? What browser do you see this in?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't like the disabled horizontal scrollbar being displayed? You can go with `overflow-y: scroll;` to force only vertical scrollbar

Comment: The overall problem is you use fixed height's everywhere and they just don't add up. If you change the `results_container`'s height to `height: 297px;` it will look okay, though you should consider to rewrite it all, since it will cause you a lot of upcoming trouble later on, when done like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted "bottom result still overflows" seems to be due to the height: 100%; CSS definition for the #wrapper div.

[image]

If you remove "height: 100%; from #wrapper, I think you'll see the results you were looking for.

Also, notice that the #wrapper div expands and collapses as the browser's display is expanded and collapsed. Once the height: 100%; is removed from #wrapper, the #wrapper height does not change.

Answer (score 1):

I made a fork from your codepen.

```
#sidebar {
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 40%;
   margin-top: 22px;
   height: 93%;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}

#results_container {
  height: 430px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Here the full example: [codepen fork](http://codepen.io/jotavejv/pen/JRgegb)